# why cannot receive jms message inside servlet in jboss

Tags: jboss, jms

if i put my jms code inside UserTransaction like:

-----------Send----------------------

```
UserTransaction.begin();
cf = (ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");

connection = cf.createConnection();

Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
javax.jms.Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
MessageProducer publisher = session.createProducer(queue);

connection.start();

TextMessage jmsMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
publisher.send(jmsMessage);
publisher.close();
connection.stop();
connection.close();

UserTransaction.commit();
```

-----------Receive----------------------

```
UserTransaction.begin();
ic = getInitialContext();
cf = (ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
connection = cf.createConnection();

Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
javax.jms.Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
MessageConsumer subscriber = session.createConsumer(queue);
connection.start();
while(true)
{
    TextMessage jmsMessage = (TextMessage)subscriber.receiveNoWait();
    if(jmsMessage == null)
    {
        break;
    }
}                
connection.close();
UserTransaction.commit();
```

---

I cannot send\receive message (I am not sure it is send fail or receive fail).

Why?